# How to load UItableList Programatically on UIview xib files

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i am loading UITableView programmatically on UIView xib file but using my below code UItableList not adding on my UIView xib file what wrong i have done here please help me some one

### mycode:-

```
  #import "FaqQuestionsClass.h"

    @implementation FaqQuestionsClass
    {
        BackGroundClass * Bg;
        UITableView * tableList;
    }
    @synthesize mainView;

    -(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

        if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

            [self loadingView];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)awakeFromNib{

        [super awakeFromNib];

        [self loadingView];
    }

    -(void)loadingView{

        Bg = [[BackGroundClass alloc]init];

        tableList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableList.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        tableList.dataSource=self;
        tableList.delegate=self;
        tableList.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        tableList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        tableList.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        tableList.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [tableList registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        [mainView addSubview:tableList];
    }

    //UITableView Delegate Methods:-

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return  10;
    }
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

        return 1;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";

        return cell;
    }

    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        return 50;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: I think problem is with your CGRectZero try to assign frame hard-coded to check whether it display table or not

Comment: hi brother how are do u remember me?

Comment: I am good, wht about u

Comment: i am also fine brother

Comment: yes brother ur correct isolve this

Comment: try it with some hardcoded value i think it will work

Comment: but why ur not responding in face book i ping u lot of times

Comment: ohhh sorry from last few days i havent open it

Comment: please respond some times i just expecting ur suggetsions

Comment: sure sure have you check this with adding some frrame

Comment: if it work plz upvote so that other can use same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103676/discussion-between-abhiram-and-vijay-palwe).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wrong frame for tableview. `CGRectZero` means that the table view is not visible on `mainView`. Update the below line

```
tableList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

with:-

```
tableList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: hi @pkc456 small dought